# How to use transactions effectively in failing queries in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit new to transaction in postgresql. I read many tutorials in it but what i want to do is that...
If i have many queries for example:

```
INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (4)
....
```

if it failed in the 3rd or any nth query because of some issue, what i want is to rollback all the other previous queries automatically.

My question is, is there any way to do that in postgresql?

Comment: What client tool/library are you using to connect to PostgreSQL?  Different tools use different method.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a transaction, PostgreSQL will automatically ROLLBACK the whole transaction if any query fails. It doesn't matter if you submit ROLLBACK or COMMIT, rollback will follow. Additionally, any query submited will end with SQL exception.

It's a strict view on **transaction concept**: all or nothing.

If you don't want such behaviour, you need to use **[savepoints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-savepoint.html)** or **plpgsql** blocks with [EXCEPTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) handling.